# Paging the result in Apache Camel LDAP Component

Tags: java, ldap, apache-camel

I need to fetch several entries (> 1000 users) from LDAP. Documentation (http://camel.apache.org/ldap.html) says there is a pageSize option for this.

pageSize
"When specified the ldap module uses paging to retrieve all results (most LDAP Servers throw an exception when trying to retrieve more than 1000 entries in one query). To be able to use this a LdapContext (subclass of DirContext) has to be passed in as ldapServerBean (otherwise an exception is thrown)"

What does this mean? How do I pass LdapContext in and how to iterate through pages? Could someone give me a simple example where many entries are fetched from LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

Except for specifying the `pageSize` parameter, there's probably nothing else that you have to do. The description clarifies a minor issue which you likely won't come across.

The `ldap` component isn't limited to reading from a `LdapContext`, it can use an instance of `DirContext` (a super-interface) instead. Using an instance of this super-interface will work *except* for setting the `pageSize`. If you follow the example from the Camel docs, you'll see that it is using `com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory` as the factory for your context bean. This class builds objects that implement `LdapContext`, and so the `pageSize` parameter should work.

For an example, you can simply add the parameter to the URI.

```
Collection<?> results = (Collection<?>) (template
  .sendBody(
    "ldap:ldapserver?base=ou=mygroup,ou=groups,ou=system&pageSize=1000",
    "(member=uid=huntc,ou=users,ou=system)"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty old, but an answer could help others as well, since the LDAP endpoint of Camel is quite unclear. Below a working example:

```
<bean id="ldapServerBean" class="javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext" scope="prototype">
<constructor-arg>
    <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">${ldap.url}</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication">simple</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">${ldap.user}</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">${ldap.password}</prop>
    </props>
</constructor-arg>
<constructor-arg>
    <null />
</constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The route:

```
<route id="LDAP" autoStartup="{{route.autoStartup}}">
    <from uri="quartz2://ldapTimer?cron={{scheduler.cron}}"/>
    <setBody><simple>{{ldap.filter}}</simple></setBody>
    <to uri="ldap:ldapServerBean?base={{ldap.base}}&amp;scope={{ldap.scope}}&amp;returnedAttributes={{ldap.returnedAttributes}}&amp;pageSize={{ldap.pageSize}}"/>
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="LDAP Result: ${body}"/>
    <to ...>
</route>
```

This way you make use of pageSize provided as parameter in the route and are able to retrieve more than 1000 records from an LDAP server.